# ImageWriter alternative for android 19-22?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

In version 23 of the android API there was the introduction of the class [ImageWriter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageWriter.html).
I need to use this class in an app that should run on api 19.
How can I re-implement the class? Is there some equivalent code (I have an Image instance I need to draw to a surface)?

Comment: You can download the Java source code for the M/6.0 preview from your SDK Manager. While it is not final, it is probably pretty close. There are 10+ `native` methods in `ImageWriter`, which means that it will be difficult to duplicate without the `media_jni` library source, and I have no idea if that native code can be built via the NDK to serve as a library for API Level 19-22. Things should become a bit clearer when Android 6.0 ships for realz and the repositories get updated with all the code. However, I am not hopeful that you will find success.

Answer (score -1):

Here you have a code which allows you to take a picture and preview it on a Surface. I'm sure you can adapt the code for your purpose.

Here's the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  />
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="#A000">
    <Button
      android:layout_width="100dip"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Cancel"
      android:onClick="onCancelClick"
    />
    <Button
      android:layout_width="100dip"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:text="Snap Photo"
      android:onClick="onSnapClick"
    />
  </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here the Java code:

```
package app.test;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class PreviewActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.ShutterCallback, Camera.PictureCallback {

    Camera mCamera;
    SurfaceView mPreview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mPreview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
        mPreview.getHolder().addCallback(this);
        mPreview.getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        mCamera = Camera.open();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mCamera.release();
        Log.d("CAMERA","Destroy");
    }

    public void onCancelClick(View v) {
        finish();
    }

    public void onSnapClick(View v) {
        mCamera.takePicture(this, null, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onShutter() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        //Here, we chose internal storage
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("picture.jpg", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            out.write(data);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        camera.startPreview();
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Camera.Size selected = sizes.get(0);
        params.setPreviewSize(selected.width,selected.height);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);

        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.i("PREVIEW","surfaceDestroyed");
    }
}
```

Comment: ImageWriter class deals with Image classes (and that's the only thing I have). How can I adapt this code to work with Image instances?

Comment: Camera creates a Image object when takes a snap

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question. For example, the question does not mention a camera.